# How many ways can you give 5 identical trophies to 150 students?

Tags: combinatorics

My attempt at this problem was $$150!\over30!30!30!30!30!5!$$ would this be correct?

Comment: Can a student receive more than one trophy ? If no, the answer should be $\binom{150}{5}$. If yes, the answer should be $150^5$

Comment: The idea you had in mind when coming up with the attempt maybe has something to do with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 5 trophies which are identical.
You want to give them to some 5 students out of 150.

The problem can therefore be restated as:

How many ways can we choose 5 students from 150?

The reason we can say this is that ordering (i.e. permutation) does not matter with identical trophies.

We therefore now have:

$$
    ways = \binom{150}{5} = \frac{150!}{5!(150-5)!}
$$

The answer you can find. :)

Edit: I'm assuming you can't give more than 1 trophy to a student.

If you can, then as Peter points out above, the answer is just $150^5$.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, I've clarified my assumption!